# How to fix the error "`data` must be a data frame, or other object coercible by `fortify()`, not a numeric vector" in R Shiny app?

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny, shiny-reactivity

I'm new to Shiny and am trying to write an app that will create a `ggplot` of indexed stock prices of one or more companies on the same graph. I have an R script that does exactly that but when I tried to implement it as a `Shiny` app, <s>I encountered the following error "More than one expression parsed."</s>  the current error I get is this:

`data` must be a data frame, or other object coercible by `fortify()`, not a numeric vector

Could you help me figure out what is going on and what I need to do to fix it?

<s>I encountered this error after fixing a previous one that told me that my "data" was not a data frame. I found on stackoverflow that I should have put in `aes_string()` rather than `aes()` while creating the output plot.</s>

I also tried putting my expression within `renderPlot()` within `eval()` but it didn't fix the problem.

Additionally, when I only put in one ticker, I get the following error:

"arguments imply differing number of rows: 1, 0"

Here is my code:

```
library(shiny)
library(tidyquant)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

#ui logic
ui <- fluidPage(
  #App title
  titlePanel("Indexed Stock Price Chart"),

  #Sidebar Layout w/ input & output definitions
  sidebarPanel(
    #Input: Enter Ticker Names
    helpText("Enter tickers separated by a comma as shown in this example: AMZN,GOOG,MSFT"),
    textInput("ticker", label = h3("Ticker(s)"), value = "Enter tickers...."),
    #Input: Date Range
    dateRangeInput("dates", label = "Date Range", start = Sys.Date()-360, end = Sys.Date()),
    #Input: Select Date Breaks
    selectInput("dateBr", label = "Choose a date break for x-axis", choices = c("1 month", "3 months", "4 months",
                                                                                "6 months", "1 year", "2 years", "3 years",
                                                                                "4 years", "5 years", "10 years"), selected = "6 months"),
    #Input: actionButton()
    actionButton("update", "Create Plot")
  ),

  mainPanel(
    plotOutput("plot1")
  )
)

#server logic
server <- function(input,output) {
  selectedData<- eventReactive(input$update,{
    start_date <- input$dates[1]
    end_date <- input$dates[2]
    dateBrInput <- input$dateBr
    symbol <- unlist(strsplit(input$ticker, ","))
    d1 <- tq_get(symbol,get = "stock.prices", from = start_date, to = end_date)
    S_index <- numeric(0)
    for (i in 1:length(symbol)){
      S_index <- c(S_index, d1$adjusted[which(d1$symbol == symbol[i] & d1$date == min(d1$date))])
    }
    index_df <- data.frame(symbol, S_index)
    new_df <- full_join(d1, index_df, by = "symbol")
    new_df$indexed_adj <- new_df$adjusted/new_df$S_index
  })

  output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
    ggplot(selectedData(),aes(x=date, y=indexed_adj,colour= symbol)) +
      geom_line() +
      xlab("Date") + ylab("Indexed SP") + 
      theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) +
      scale_x_date(date_labels = "%b %y", date_breaks = dateBrInput) + 
      theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
            panel.background = element_blank(), axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"))+
      labs(color = "Company") + theme(legend.title = element_blank())
  })
}


shinyApp (ui = ui, server = server)
```

I want to create a Shiny app that allows users to enter ticker names, a start and an end date, and choose date breaks for the x-axis to create a time series plot of X number of companies' stock prices. However, currently my code gives me an error saying "data must be a data frame, or other object coercible by `fortify()`, not a numeric vector" and does not generate the graph I want to plot.

Comment: You're probably getting that error here: `aes_string(x=date, y=new_df$indexed_adj`, where your x variable comes from `selectedData()` while your y-variable comes from `new_df. When plotting with ggplot, you should have all the data in a single data frame

Comment: Also, it's unclear why you used `aes_string`? When you write this: `aes_string(x=date`, ggplot looks for a object named `date` in the environment, and then looks for a variable with that name. From the look of your code, I think you'd want a normal `aes` here

Comment: Yet, not putting it into `aes_string()` gives me the following error: `data` must be a data frame, or other object coercible by `fortify()`, not a numeric vector, so is the problem with my `x` and `y` in `aes()` still? What would be the appropriate format to select these variables? Doing `aes(x=selectedData$date, y=selectedData$indexed_adj,colour= symbol))` gives me the same error.

Comment: That error is referring to the object passed to your data argument, which is `selectedData()`. The problem there might be that you don't `return(new_df)` in that function, so you only get the implicit return from the last line which is just the `indexed_adj` variable. Try adding that to `selectedData`.

Comment: Also, **don't use $ in your `aes` function**. Just pass in the *name* of the variable in the data frame that you gave to the data argument. Also, since this is a shiny app, there is no data frame called `selectedData`. `selectedData` is a function that, when called, returns a data frame. To access the data returned by it, you need to call it with parentheses like `selectedData()`

Comment: Thank you @divibisan. I updated my code and my question since I'm now back to getting the data frame error.

Comment: You're having problems in your `selectedData` function. `d1` does not a have a column called `symbol`, so when you do `which(d1$symbol`, it returns an error and disrupts the whole process of the function.

Comment: For debugging like this, you should be looking in the RStudio console, which shows errors as they're encountered. You can also put in `print` statements to see what's happening in a function. I found this by putting `print(head(d1))` right after `d1 <- tq_get( ...` which showed that `d1` does not have a symbol column

Comment: Thank you, @divibisan. This was helpful and I got the code to work. Adding a `print()` expression at the end of the `selectedData()` solved my problem. Thank you again.